# Inductively showing $g(s) = 3(g(s-1)+g(s-2))+1$ is odd for all $s$

Tags: proof-writing, induction

How would I show this equation is odd by using the induction hypothesis: 
$$
g(s) = 3(g(s-1))+(g(s-2))+1
$$
I was thinking that I would prove $g(s)$ is odd by $g(s+1) = 3(g(s)+g(s-1))+1$.

How would I proceed using the induction hypothesis?

Comment: What is an "odd" equation ? $g(0)=0\land g(1)=1$ give $g(2)=4$. This is odd.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to check the hypothesis for eg. $s=0$ and $s=1$ depending on the starting condition. That is, we check if the first two values are odd.

Then we assume that $g(s)$ is odd for all $s\in\mathbb{Z}$, where $s\leq k$. This is our induction hypothesis. Like you write, we have
\begin{align*}
g(k+1)=3\big(g(k)+g(k-1)\big)+1.
\end{align*}

Can you see how we may use the induction hypothesis now?

Solution:

> From the induction hypothesis, both $g(k)$ and $g(k-1)$ are odd, so $3\big(g(k)+g(k-1)\big)$ is even. Thus, $g(k+1)$ must be odd.

Comment: I can't see any starting conditions - If there were any they would have been given.

Comment: The starting conditions were g(1) = 1 and g(2) = 1

Comment: @user3472296: Then the initial step is to check that both $g(1)$ and $g(2)$ are odd (which they are).